# This code snippet isn't working as expected (VBScript)

Tags: scripting, vbscript

```
        Dim value
        value = CDate(InputBox("Please enter the time (hh:mm)", "Time Input", FormatDateTime(Now, 4)))          
        ' validate the input here
        WScript.Echo value
        internal_Time = CDate(FormatDateTime(value, 4))
```

I am expecting the time to be as 08:24 or 13:12 but it's appearing as 8:26:12 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
internal_Time = CDate(FormatDateTime(value, 4))
```

Your formatting to a *string* but then converting back to a *Date*, so the formatting is lost and the value is converted to a VB Date value that includes AM/PM, if its for display then just store the string:

```
internal_Time = FormatDateTime(value, 4)
```